# Android connected to printer, printed PDF document, document was reduced

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing

I set up PrintAttributes for printing PDF documents, the paper size is set to A3, but when it is connected to the wifi printer, it is reduced and cannot print 100%. ：

```
PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                    .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3)
                    .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("id", Context.PRINT_SERVICE, 96, 96))
                    .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
                    .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
                    .build();
```

But I printed the same PDF document using the computer connected printer, and its size was correct, Does anyone know what the reason is? I tried different models of printers from HP and Canon.

Comment: You've got an A4 document?

Comment: I also tried to print on A4 paper, which was also reduced. @g00se